# Calendar working days - set start and end days to sunrise and sunset

Tags: calendar, date-time

Can the working day of a calendar be set to the sunrise/sunset?  I found javascript to calculate sunrise and sunset given a date and lat/long info.  This would calculate the sunrise/sunset of the current day only.  Can each working day start/end be different?  And how does one grab each day of the calendar and feed it to the javascript?

Comment: By calendar you mean a SharePoint calendar? Posters should be really learn to give more context to their questions. Of course you can "feed it to javascript" (in many different ways, btw). But how and where do you want to put/store/show sunrise and sunset information? What is the goal and how/where are you going to use this? Without these elements, you'll hardly get any answer here

Comment: Yes, a SharePoint calendar (this is a SharePoint form after all)

It's not a matter of storing sunrise/sunset info.  It would be calculated given a day and a lat/long which would be coded in.  This algorithm explains how to calculate sunrise/sunset for a given day and location: http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm.  This explains how to programmatically set start/end times: http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-to-change-SharePoint-Calendar-default-start-hour-and-end-hour-of-Day-View.aspx.  But am I able to have different start/end days for each day?

Comment: You never told me if my answer was of any usefulness

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best you can do, provided that you can set the start time/end time for a Site, but this will affect all the calendars within it and consequently all the days.

The solution I'm going to propose is a dirty hack, so bear with me if it's far from being perfect.

You'll require:

- jQuery (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544538/JQuery-with-SharePoint-2010) how to add it to SharePoint)
- a CEWP (content editor web part)
- a js file uploaded to a doc library of your choice (eg. the Site Assets library)

**Step 1:**

Go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Regional Settings. Set Start time to 00:00 and End time to 23:00. **Don't forget to do this, or the trick won't work.**

**Step 2:**

Go to `http://yoursite/yourcalendar/calendar.aspx.` Click on Site Actions > Edit Page, then add a CEWP to the bottom of the page, right below the monthly calendar view.
Edit the properties of the CEWP and link to eg. /SiteAssets/cal.js.

**Step 3:**
Create a js file in the SiteAssets library, name it cal.js.
Put this code inside it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("tweakCalendar");

function tweakCalendar(){   
var selectedDate = $('.ms-picker-dayselected').length ? $('.ms-picker-dayselected a').attr('id') : $('.ms-picker-today a').attr('id');
var yyyy = parseInt(selectedDate.substr(0,4));
var mm = parseInt(selectedDate.substr(4,2)) - 1;
var dd = parseInt(selectedDate.substr(6,2));
var date = new Date(yyyy, mm , dd);

// with the date, call your function to get sunset / sunrise. 
// You must convert your result to an integer (eg. sunrise 06:23 -> 6 )
var sunset;     //tbd
var sunrise;    //tbd

// hide all time slots before sunrise
$('a[evtid="click_time"]').filter(function(){  return parseInt($(this).attr('time'))  == sunrise }).parents('.ms-acal-hour00:first').prevAll().hide();

// hide all time slots after sunset
$('a[evtid="click_time"]').filter(function(){  return parseInt($(this).attr('time'))  == sunset }).parents('.ms-acal-hour00:first').nextAll().hide();
}
</script>
```

**Step 4:**

In order for the script to work, you must call your calendar view by forcing the daily view.
Just add `?CalendarPeriod=day` to the calendar.aspx url. Eg. `http://yoursite/calendar/calendar.aspx?CalendarPeriod=day`